# Python_input txt file by the cmd

Tags: python

[image]

I had this error when I trying to use example from CS50 introduction in AI course
I use win 10 in my end , they using MAC its worked in their end but didn't work in my end
what is the issue or what I need to do to run this txt file with my code using the windows terminal

Comment: Have you downloaded `maze3,txt` and stored in the same directory as `maze.py`?

Comment: where's the code?

Comment: I have maze3.txt  on my Desktop

Comment: how can i send you the code its too long to be paste here ? is there any way to send it to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running maze.py from "C:>"

1. Open file explorer.
2. Navigate to your Desktop
3. In the top type cmd

[image: In the top type cmd]

4. Pess Enter
5. In cmd run

   maze.py maze3.txt

Comment: I'm happy to hear that! I would appreciate vote up in my answer!

Comment: Thank you  for your answer its great

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `maze3.txt` file is in you Desktop, from where you're running the script. From the error, it seems like that file is not there.

Comment: I have it in my desktop but same issue